# Eloquent: Retrieve pluck collection with trashed entries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pluck

I want to get all Address IDs, including the trashed ones, with pluck. This is how it is working but I don't get the trashed ones as well:

```
$clientIDs = Client::pluck('address_id')->all();
```

This is what I tried already:

```
$clientIDs = Client::pluck('address_id')
                        ->withTrashed()
                        ->get();
```

Throws: `Method withTrashed does not exist.`

How can I use pluck and withTrashed() and solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pluck()` already finalises the query and retrieves the info from the database for you. So the `->all()` call is redundant for that - what it does is convert the Eloquent collection into an array.

For that reason, you're calling `withTrashed()` after the query has already been executed. Move them and it'll work:

```
$clientIds = Client::withTrashed()->pluck('address_id'); // no need for ->get()
```